# Incorrect sudo password while fetching password from vault

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm using a vault file, storing ssh password and become password.
In the playbook I'm using `set_fact` to define `ansible_become_pass`.

But it does not work.
If I add `ansible_become_pass: host1_password` in vars, it works.

So it seems like something is getting added while I'm doing this and I will receive a "Incorrect sudo password"

So what I'm i doing wrong?

Example.
Vault file:

```yaml
host1:
  ansible_ssh_pass: host1_password
  ansible_become_pass: host1_password
```

Example.
Playbook file:

```yaml
- name: Attach to host
  hosts: host1
  vars_files:
    - vault/{{ ansible_user_id }}.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Set Facts
      set_fact:
        ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ ansible_hostname }}.ansible_ssh_pass"
#        ansible_sudo_pass: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_hostname'] }}.ansible_become_pass"
        ansible_become_pass: "{{ ansible_hostname }}.ansible_become_pass"
#        ansible_sudo_pass: "{{ ansible_hostname }}.ansible_become_pass"

    - name: show ansible_become_pass
      debug:
        var: '{{ ansible_hostname }}.ansible_become_pass'

    - name: show set_fact ansible_become_pass
      debug:
        var: "{{ ansible_become_pass }}"

    - name: hostname
      shell: ls 
      become: true
      register: host_name

    - name: debug hostname  
      debug:
        var: host_name
```

adding `ansible_become_pass` as variable does work. But I want to use Vault for this

```yaml
ansible_become_pass: host1_password
```

Answer (score 0):

Typical setup for this with a fully encrypted vault file in your inventory.

*Note: you can also add encrypted strings inside a plaintext inventory or any adjacent var file using `ansible-vault encrypt_string yourstring`*

---

`inventories/production/hosts.yml`

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
```

---

`inventories/production/host_vars/host1/encrypted.yml`
*Note: this is the plaintext decrypted version. The encrypted file will be decoded on the fly with your provided vault password*

```yaml
---
ansible_ssh_pass: host1_ssh_password
ansible_become_pass: host1_become_password
```

---

If you then have a (dummy example) playbook like:

```yaml
- name: dummy example
  hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: A dummy task ran with become
      shell: id -a
```

you can run it with:

```
ansible-playbook --ask-vault-pass -i inventories/production my_dummy_playbook.yml
```

For more info on how to construct your inventory, see [how to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html)

For more info on how to encrypt files or unitary strings, ways to provide your vault password, using several passwords with vault ids an and more see [the vault documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vault_guide/index.html)

Comment: I can’t see how this answer my question!?

Comment: `So what I'm i doing wrong?` => you're reinventing the wheel by manually loading var files in your play and you set facts when there is no need for that. Moreover, there are no debugging details. The above is simply a typical setup to do exactly what you describe: store the connect/become password depending on each host in a vault encrypted file, connect and launch become tasks as needed with those individual passwords, and that setup "works". If you feel there are details missing, you might consider [editing](/posts/76316974/edit) your question and provide more information like a [mre].

Comment: "Ah, I understand what you mean. But I want to have the current passwords in the same file. This file should only be used by me, and if someone else is going to run this playbook, their password file should be used. But maybe I'm thinking wrong here?"